# NullReferenceException when grouping collection by arrays in powershell

Tags: powershell, exception, grouping

Very simple scenario:

- there's an array of logs parsed from the file
- each log has property `Exceptions` that is array of exceptions parsed from log body

---

```
$logs | Get-Member
Name        MemberType Definition
----        ---------- ----------
Equals      Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method     int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method     type GetType()
ToString    Method     string ToString()
Content     Property   string Content {get;set;}
Exceptions  Property   string[] Exceptions {get;set;}
Line        Property   int Line {get;set;}
Source      Property   string Source {get;set;}
Time        Property   System.Nullable[datetime] Time {get;set;}
```

Unit tests on parser confirm that `Exceptions` is never null.
Also:

```
$logs | where {$_.Exceptions -eq $null} | measure

Count    : 0
Average  : 
Sum      : 
Maximum  : 
Minimum  : 
Property :
```

But:

```
$logs | group {$_.Exceptions}
group : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
At line:1 char:6
+ $l | group {$_.Exceptions}
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Group-Object], NullReferenceException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NullReferenceException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GroupObjectCommand
```

So considering that the check measuring number of elements with null Exceptions returned zero this should work exactly as the call above:

```
$logs | where Exceptions -ne $null | group {$_.Exceptions}
```

But this time it succeeds:

```
Values : {SecurityException}
Count  : 28
Group  : {ErrorLog, ErrorLog, ErrorLog, ErrorLog...}
Name   : SecurityException 

Values : {ValidationException}
Count  : 707
Group  : {ErrorLog, ErrorLog, ErrorLog, ErrorLog...}
Name   : ValidationException

Values : {SoapException ValidationException}
Count  : 6
Group  : {ErrorLog, ErrorLog, ErrorLog, ErrorLog...}
Name   : SoapException ValidationException
```

The question is **why it succeeds after I filter out all the elements with null `Exceptions` while measure-object suggests that there's nothing null in there**?

Solution for grouping my logs (good enough, because I don't need groups, just count of specific occurences) :

```
function Group-Logs([Log[]]$logs)
{
    $logs | where {$_.Exceptions.Count -gt 0} | group {$_.Exceptions} -NoElement | sort Count

    $noExceptionsLogsNumber = ($logs | where {$_.Exceptions.Count -eq 0}).Count
    Write-Host "Logs with no exceptions found: $noExceptionsLogsNumber"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the Exceptions property is a string array.  All comparison operators work as both scalar (single item) and array operators.  When used against a scalar, it returns a boolean ($true/$false).  When used against an array it returns all member of the array that match the condition.

```
$logs | where {$_.Exceptions -eq $null} | measure
```

Returns 0 items because there are no null strings in the $_.Exceptions array.

Comment: That's already something, thanks :) I actually ran this `$logs | where {$_.Exceptions.Count -eq 0} | measure` and found out that the result is exactly the number of logs that have no exceptions. 
So I believe that when I call `Group-Object` on the arrays it compares the strings within and either null is not satisfying here or as a key for creating group. Is there some way I can force `Group-Object` to work with empty arrays without discarding them or addind empty strings?